# Counting users by changes in column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting stumped by a rather simple looking problem.

I have a table with three columns, dates, customer_ids and status. We are using it to track the status of customer ids - which can either be paying, trial or expired. So each customer id is repeated everyday from the time it is logged in the system

I'd like to run a query that counts the number of custids which goes from trial to paying. I have joined the table to itself or used sub queries etc but nothing seems to give me the right results.

```
date         custid   status
2018/1/1     1        trial
2018/1/2     1        trial
2018/1/3     1        paying
2018/1/1     2        trial
2018/1/1     2        trial
2018/1/1     2        expired
```

Comment: Can a user have multiple rows for paying?  Can a user go back and forth more than once?

Comment: yes. when a user goes to paying, they are shown as paying for each subsequent date. However, they might also deactivate and reactivate their account again, so going from paying to expired to paying again.

Comment: Can a customer go straight to `paying` without a `trial` first?  Can they then let it `expire`, start a `trial`, but not go on to paying?  *(`paying` -> `expired` -> `trial` -> `expired`?)*

Comment: @MatBailie  yes , we have seen that scenario before.

Comment: So, in short, you want a count of users that are _currently_ 'paying' and have at least once been 'trial'?

Comment: @MickMnemonic no, I am looking to count users who convert - number of users going from trial to paying

Comment: So, you specifically want the number of customers who go `trial` -> `paying` with nothing in between?  What if one customer manages that twice? Should they still only be counted once?

Comment: @MatBailie - I want a count of cust ids anytime that event occurs - so regardless of whats in between, if they go from trial -> paying, we see that as one distinct event.

Comment: That seems contradictory.  You want the ***"event"*** `'trial'` -> `'paid'`, but ***"regardless of what's in between"***?  So, if one customer goes `trial, expired, paying, expired, trial, paying`, is that two cases, or one?

Comment: @MatBailie - that will be two. we are counting every trial -> paying event, so not contradictory

Comment: I would suggest that an "event" implies something instantaneous, not something that can take months.  In your case I could have a trial until 31/12/2016. be expired for every date in 2017 and start paying in 2018, and still count once to your totals.  To me that's not an event ;)  But I *can* give you a solution, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Show better sample data which will cover edge cases and add the expected result.

Comment: When you get to this many comments... well, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only go from trial to paying once (i.e. can't start a new trial once you've bought it), you could do

```
select count(1)
from ( select distinct custid
       from foo
       where status = 'paying' ) P
inner join ( select distinct custid
             from foo
             where status = 'trial') T On P.custid = T.custid
```

If you want to restrict on date range, add that to the inner sub-select that generates `P`

Comment: pls see my comments above. the user can flip between paying to expired to trial again.  An expired account can be reactivated into a new trial.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, you can just filter by `'paying'`.  Let me assume that once someone is paying, they have multiple rows.

If I assume that once someone is paying, they never go back.  Then, you want the minimum paid date for customers that also have a free trial:

```
select min_paid_date, count(*)
from (select custid, min(case when status = 'paying' then date end) as min_paid_date
      from t
      group by custid
      having sum( status = 'trial' ) > 0
     ) c
group by min_paid_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This counts the number of occurrences of customers transitioning from 'trial' on one day to 'paying' on the next day.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  yourTable   trials
INNER JOIN
  yourTable   paying
    ON  paying.custid = trials.custid
    AND paying.date   = trials.date + 1
WHERE
      trials.status = 'trial'
  and paying.status = 'paying'
```

Comment: this is not right:  trial, trial, expired , paying, paying.  Maybe we are not on the same page. there is no direct trial -> paying event in this scenario.

Comment: @user2022284 - OMG, I expicitly asked about that in the comments...   Figure out what you want and then figure out how to precisely and accurately describe it!  You're wasting out time now...

Comment: @user2022284 ***ME*** : `So, if one customer goes trial, expired, paying, expired, trial, paying, is that two cases, or one?`

Comment: @user2022284 ***YOU*** : `that will be two`

Comment: I answered your question correctly. a user can have any number of pathways but i did also state clearly i wanted to track instances ( or events) of trial to paying only. So not sure where I got it wrong

Comment: @user2022284 - YOU SAID IT WOULD BE ***TWO***, NOW YOU'RE SAYING THAT'S WRONG

Comment: ok. I totally misread that posting. I read it as :  trial, expired, trial, paying, trial, paying.  ( because a user cant directly go from expired to paying) . I just misinterpreted what you typed.

Comment: Not my intention. I could genuinely do with the help